# Problems in using library headers with Android JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm using ndk 5 and the samples are build fine. But in project when I added the line
`#include <SLES/OpenSLES.h>`
It gives compilation error that there is no such file or directory.
My Android.mk is exactly like the one from native-audio except for the source file name.

What is the problem?
Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: The only differnce is that my file is cpp

Comment: What SDK version are you targeting?

Comment: Thanks Maximus - I was targeting for the wrong SDK version\

Answer (score 6):

Try:

ndk-build TARGET_PLATFORM=android-9